# Google Data Studio: adds a prefix to the column and throws a error

Tags: google-bigquery, calculated-field, looker-studio

I am trying to use Median function in Google Data studio to create a calculated field but when it runs and it adds "t0." before the columns name and a error pops up

There`s a query error.

Field 't0.WordsFound' not found; did you mean 'WordsFound'?

Error ID: 62b13613

I am aware that it adds a prefix to most parameters at run time but for some reason for this Median function its not working. If I go into Big Query and find the actual query in the "Query History" and remove the prefix the query works. Its really confusing.